# Is it possible to end Quickblox session without logout request in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, quickblox

I know that to end correctly current quickblox session I need to logout user. However I have a case when user can be logged out if he received 401 and cannot refresh token on my own app backend.
So I end my user session but current QBSession is not finished. So as Quickblox user - is still logged in. And I'm afraid even can receive pushes in logout state. 
Is there a way to force finish quickblox session without logout request?
Another SDK for PushNotifications OneSignal has method OneSignal.setSubscription(_ subscribtion: Bool). So I can simply set it to "false" and it will notify OneSignal backend that current user shouldn't receive pushes.

Of course I can try to perform logout request when I redirect user to login page but it might fails because of missing connection. 
So some way to end current Quickblox session without logout or even some flag isLogged might be very helpful for my case.

Also do I need to disconnect from chat on logout?

Note:
I'm using latest QuickBlox SDK 2.10 and Swift 3.